# Less Project included Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a simple but for me rather an important question. I will start a clean Project with Less and wanna include bootstrap. So my basic style.less file would look like this:

```
// Bootstrap Corefile
@import "bootstrap.less";

// My own Styles
header {
  .make-row();
}
```

is this logical correct because now the bootstrap and my own styles are compressed in one file. In addition I would have a pretty big css file... And what if I want to use another css file from external plugins.

I would like to know if someone has already experience with it?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that will work. If you want to add another file you can just import that as well.

One thing that you do have to be careful of is that in the earlier version of IE it has a max number of classes it process. I can't remember off the top of my head but I think it is somewhere near 1000. So if the css at the end of the file isnt working in IE thats why.

Here is a line to the [documentation](http://lesscss.org/) to see what you can do with it. Check out the import section.

Comment: Wow, hearing this the first time with the IE. Very good to know, thank you. So at the end it would be better to compress the whole file?

Comment: I use a bit of software that compiles my less and if it is over a certain size it makes two css files. Thats how I found out about it. Im not sure weather it is the size of the files or how many classes there are so compressing the file might not help. To be fair the number of classes you can have is very large so I wouldnt worry too much.