# Using Bootstrap Less Variables without Import?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

i alerady asked a similar question here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630854/less-project-included-bootstrap)

Now i have another question to the bootstrap less variables. I created now an own style.less file

```
// My own Styles
header {
 .make-row();
}
```

if i run the compile now, i get errors --> obv he dont know the variable **.make-row();**
Is it possible to use all the bootstrap less variables without importing the bootstrap.less corefile into my style.less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, just import the "mixins.less" file at the top of your "style.less"

```
@import "mixins.less";
```